# NameError when trying to run a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to use threading in order to run while true loops constantly while running different functions as well, but the problem is I receive a `NameError` whenever I try to thread

Here's the code:

```py
import threading

wallet = 0

t1 = threading.Thread(target=lemon_mon)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=melon_mon)
t1.start()
t2.start()
def lemon_mon():
    global wallet
    while True:
        wallet += 1
        print(wallet)
def melon_mon():
    while True:
        wallet += 1
        print(wallet)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
line 8, in <module>
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lemon_mon) NameError: name 'lemon_mon' is not defined
```

Comment: Move your functions above where you define the threads.

Comment: @AlexKosh What do you mean by "don't post code"? We definitely *require* debugging questions to include the code which needs to be debugged.

Comment: @tripleee I mean that there might be a better question like "How to hanldle NameError in Python", which can be easyly solwed with google, and not by asking external SO question

Comment: @tripleee Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Prefered way is to search for answer, especially easy one like this, but not creating questions with full code without any thinking process

Comment: @AlexKosh 

i appreciate the help from both of you,and i don't normally use stackover flow i've only posted about 3 or 2 questions and i always get corrected by someone and tbh there correction always makes sense and i always think to myself how i didn't notice it

and I don't really understand how stackoverflow works yet and i thought posting this question would help me get an idea and also get a solution

Comment: @AlexKosh


the thing is i tried working with threads before and it always used to work and nobody on yt mentioned that you should use def before threading and i did try a multiple other solutions before coming here on stack so yeah thanks alot for the both of you and have a good night

sorry too long had to send 2 comments haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your functions above the threading objects. Also in your `melon_mon()` function I believe that you should call global for wallet as well

Comment: Thanks alot that helped me since no videos on the youtube mentioned that

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should define functions before using them, so the code will be:

```
import threading

wallet = 0
def lemon_mon():
    global wallet
    while True:
        wallet += 1
        print(wallet)

def melon_mon():
    global wallet
    while True:
        wallet += 1
        print(wallet)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=lemon_mon)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=melon_mon)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Also you should read more about Python threading.